# Library that can enable / disable zoom and panning function in imageview

Tags: android, canvas, zooming, android-imageview

I was working on a custom imageview that can zoom and panning, the problem is there seems no one can active/ inactive the zooming function

For example, if I can press a button, and call some function like view.active() then the view can zoom , or view.inactive() to disable zoom temporary.

All found library are:

https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview

It seems I need to remove/ edit the listener. The PhotoView library has setZoomEnable function but there is a problem that, the zoom level reset but not retain when active/ inactive.

Are there any apporach / library to create such imageview? Thanks for helping.